# Is there a way to publish a Spring web-service endpoint only for a specific environment?

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-ws

There is a web-application that uses `WebServiceTemplate` from `spring-ws` to consume remote SOAP-based web-services.
I would like to create a web-service endpoint ("mocking" the remote endpoints) so that it can be used when the remote web-service is down. However, I want this "mocked" web-service to be reachable only from the environment used for development, it shouldn't be published in other environments (e.g.: Integration, Test, Production, etc.).
The current environment can be determined from a configuration-entry.
Is there a way I can publish a web-service with spring in such a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create this mock object only in dev environment then you should use Spring's @Conditional annotation. Here's an [example](http://www.javarticles.com/2016/01/spring-conditional-annotation-example.html).